# Dealing with links to documents

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, hyperlinks

I was reading [Extracting tree crown areas from remote sensing data (visual images and LiDAR)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124224/extracting-tree-crown-areas-from-remote-sensing-data-visual-images-and-lidar) with interest and saw a comment made by @Aaron about links to documents breaking and how answers should be better than a 1 liner.

This got me thinking after I had followed the link to the paper. Just about any decent Journal utilises the [DOI](http://www.doi.org/factsheets/DOIKeyFacts.html).  So my suggestion and I have no idea how difficult it would be to implement in GIS StackExchange is to have another button or augment the current link button to allow a user to specifically enter the DOI number. In theory @Aarons arguments should go away as the DOI is unique and persists.

http://doi.org/10.3390/s141222643

Just an idea?

Comment: That is a good idea.  Although providing a full reference to the literature would also work.

Comment: unfortunately it does not help when links break (as many websites get revamped way to too often).

Comment: @Mapperz, so you have had a doi link fail on you?

Comment: doi is ok but the link through is unavailable http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/springerreference_62186

Comment: Interesting I have always understood the doi was a solution to all these problems, clearly not!

Comment: @Mapperz [According to the authorities](https://dx.doi.org/), that's not a correct DOI. Where did it come from?

Comment: This would need to be implemented SE network-wide rather than locally at GIS SE so I have set it to [meta-tag:status-deferred] i.e. deferred to [meta.se].

Answer (score 1):

This was asked long ago but has not been answered.

To implement this would need to be a SE network-wide enhancement and much broader than the slight site customization that we can achieve internal to GIS SE.

Consequently, I recommend that you research it at [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) instead of here.  I just [did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=doi) and found the Q&A to [Add explicit support for citing scientific literature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116397/add-explicit-support-for-citing-scientific-literature) that looks hopeful.